# PHP HTTP headers always returns 3.82.21.84 in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, ip, custom-wordpress-pages

I need to print a user city on the webpage based on the user's IP address. I tried to read the IP address from `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, but it always returns the same `3.82.21.84` address no matter what the IP is. I am using it as a WordPress site, so I think there is some plugin or internal WordPress error. I used the following function to print IP on a custom PHP-coded site, and it worked perfectly, but when the same function I pasted in WordPress, it crashed the Admin Panel. Below is the function.

```
function getUserIP()
{
    // Get real visitor IP behind CloudFlare network
    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"])) {
        $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
        $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
    }
    $client = @$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    $forward = @$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    $remote = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    if (filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $client;
    } elseif (filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
        $ip = $forward;
    } else {
        $ip = $remote;
    }

    return $ip;
}

$user_ip = getUserIP();
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$user_ip}/json"));
echo "<b style='color:black !important;'>$user_ip</b>";
```

The above code works for my other custom build website, but when I use it in WordPress, the site crashes, saying "Critical error." So I used `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` to get IP in the site, and it is always '3.82.21.84'. Any suggestions will be highly welcomed.

Comment: Your code sits behind a load balancer or proxy, and the IP is of that. Check `$forward`, it contains the real addresses from behind the proxy/LB

Comment: `3.82.21.84` is an Amazon EC2 address. Have you checked your other values to see what they contain? You may need to change your order of checks.

Comment: just to add: the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR can contain a list of IP addresses, not only a single IP address..

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I am also thinking of the same that something is hiding the real IP. When I use this code that has data that is in $forward and $client my site crashes. Is there anything that WordPress is not allowing?

Comment: @aynber can you please specify what other values should I check.

Comment: @LarsStegelitz I have edited description a little.

Comment: Debug your code... you try to decode some file contents, but I assume the `$user_ip` has an unexpected value (invalid URL, response is not what you've expected).

Comment: It is done. I used `$_SERVER[HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_FORWARDED_FOR]` to get the real IP address. It was quite a simple one. Thank you for your time I really appreciate that.